# Showing Wrong Language in window title and messagebox : win32 application, opengl

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to create a basic window with opengl and win32 application in visual studio 2013.
Everything works fine except the window title and messages in messagebox are not showing English. My code is given below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ThesisProject.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// ================================= Variable Region : All the global variables will be declared here with categorization =========================== //

TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
HDC hDC = NULL;    // Private GDI Device Context. GDI : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface
HWND hWnd = NULL; // holds our window handle. 
HINSTANCE hInstance; // holds the instance of the application
HGLRC hRC = NULL; // Permanent Rendering Context

bool keys[256]; // Array Used for the keyboard routine. this will help us to track multiple key press, like : "Ctrl + s"
bool active = TRUE; // window active flag. set to true by default. 
bool fullscreen = TRUE; // fullscreen flag. set to true by default. indicates whether the screen should be windowed or fullscreen.

// ================================================================================================================================================== //

// ================================ Function prototype declaration region : all the function prototype declaration will go here. ====================== //

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // a call back function to process window action.

int InitGL(GLvoid); // this function is used for setting up opengl components.
BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag); // creates the window.
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid); // this is where all the drawing goes.
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height); // this function is used to handle the properties when the window is resized when full screen mode is not used.
GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid); // this function is called before closing the window.

// =================================================================================================================================================== //

// this function is the entry point of this project . what ever this program does, it starts from here.
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
_In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
_In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
_In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;                                // Windows Message Structure
    BOOL    done = FALSE;                         // Bool Variable To Exit Loop

    // Create Our OpenGL Window
    if (!CreateGLWindow("OpenGL Testing", 640, 480, 16, fullscreen))
    {
        return 0;                           // Quit If Window Was Not Created
    }

    while (!done)                                // Loop That Runs Until done=TRUE
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))           // Is There A Message Waiting?
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)               // Have We Received A Quit Message?
            {
                done = TRUE;                  // If So done=TRUE
            }
            else                            // If Not, Deal With Window Messages
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);             // Translate The Message
                DispatchMessage(&msg);              // Dispatch The Message
            }
        }
        else                                // If There Are No Messages
        {
            // Draw The Scene.  Watch For ESC Key And Quit Messages From DrawGLScene()
            if (active)                     // Program Active?
            {
                if (keys[VK_ESCAPE])                // Was ESC Pressed?
                {
                    done = TRUE;              // ESC Signalled A Quit
                }
                else                        // Not Time To Quit, Update Screen
                {
                    DrawGLScene();              // Draw The Scene
                    SwapBuffers(hDC);           // Swap Buffers (Double Buffering)
                }
            }
            if (keys[VK_F1])                    // Is F1 Being Pressed?
            {
                keys[VK_F1] = FALSE;              // If So Make Key FALSE
                KillGLWindow();                 // Kill Our Current Window
                fullscreen = !fullscreen;             // Toggle Fullscreen / Windowed Mode
                // Recreate Our OpenGL Window
                if (!CreateGLWindow("Aqib", 640, 480, 16, fullscreen))
                {
                    return 0;               // Quit If Window Was Not Created
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Shutdown
    KillGLWindow();                             // Kill The Window
    return (msg.wParam);                            // Exit The Program
}

// this function is used to initialize all the opengl components.
int InitGL(GLvoid){
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);               // enabling smooth shader
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // black background

    glClearDepth(1.0f);                    // depth buffer setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);               // enable depth testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                // the type of depth test to do

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);     // really nice perspective calculations
    return TRUE;                           // initialization went ok
}

// this function creates and registers the window to the OS.
BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag){
    GLuint      PixelFormat;                        // Holds The Results After Searching For A Match

    WNDCLASS    wc;                         // Windows Class Structure

    DWORD       dwExStyle;                      // Window Extended Style
    DWORD       dwStyle;                        // Window Style

    RECT WindowRect;                            // Grabs Rectangle Upper Left / Lower Right Values
    WindowRect.left = (long)0;                        // Set Left Value To 0
    WindowRect.right = (long)width;                       // Set Right Value To Requested Width
    WindowRect.top = (long)0;                         // Set Top Value To 0
    WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;                     // Set Bottom Value To Requested Height

    fullscreen = fullscreenflag;                      // Set The Global Fullscreen Flag

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);            // Grab An Instance For Our Window
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;       // Redraw On Move, And Own DC For Window
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;                // WndProc Handles Messages
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;                        // No Extra Window Data
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                        // No Extra Window Data
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;                    // Set The Instance
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);          // Load The Default Icon
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);          // Load The Arrow Pointer
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;                     // No Background Required For GL
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                     // We Don't Want A Menu
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)"OpenGLTesting";                 // Set The Class Name

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))                        // Attempt To Register The Window Class
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Failed To Register The Window Class.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Exit And Return FALSE
    }

    if (fullscreen){                             // Attempt Fullscreen Mode?
        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;                   // Device Mode
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));       // Makes Sure Memory's Cleared
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);       // Size Of The Devmode Structure
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width;            // Selected Screen Width
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;           // Selected Screen Height
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = bits;             // Selected Bits Per Pixel
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        // Try To Set Selected Mode And Get Results.  NOTE: CDS_FULLSCREEN Gets Rid Of Start Bar.
       if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL){
            // If The Mode Fails, Offer Two Options.  Quit Or Run In A Window.
            fullscreen = FALSE;
       }
    }

    if (fullscreen){                             // Are We Still In Fullscreen Mode?
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;                  // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle = WS_POPUP;                       // Windows Style
        ShowCursor(TRUE);                      // Hide Mouse Pointer
    }
    else{
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;           // Window Extended Style
        dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;                    // Windows Style
    }

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);     // Adjust Window To True Requested Size

    if (!(hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,              // Extended Style For The Window
        (LPCWSTR)"OpenGLTesting",               // Class Name
        (LPCWSTR)title,                  // Window Title
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |           // Required Window Style
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN |           // Required Window Style
        dwStyle,                // Selected Window Style
        0, 0,                   // Window Position
        WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left,   // Calculate Adjusted Window Width
        WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top,   // Calculate Adjusted Window Height
        NULL,                   // No Parent Window
        NULL,                   // No Menu
        hInstance,              // Instance
        NULL)))
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Window Creation Error.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;
    }

    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =                  // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),                  // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
        1,                              // Version Number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                       // Must Support Double Buffering
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                          // Request An RGBA Format
        bits,                               // Select Our Color Depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                       // Color Bits Ignored
        0,                              // No Alpha Buffer
        0,                              // Shift Bit Ignored
        0,                              // No Accumulation Buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                         // Accumulation Bits Ignored
        16,                             // 16Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)
        0,                              // No Stencil Buffer
        0,                              // No Auxiliary Buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                         // Main Drawing Layer
        0,                              // Reserved
        0, 0, 0                             // Layer Masks Ignored
    };

    if (!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))                         // Did We Get A Device Context?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Can't Create A GL Device Context.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))             // Did Windows Find A Matching Pixel Format?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, PixelFormat, &pfd))               // Are We Able To Set The Pixel Format?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Can't Set The PixelFormat.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!(hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC)))                   // Are We Able To Get A Rendering Context?
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Can't Create A GL Rendering Context.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))                        // Try To Activate The Rendering Context
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Can't Activate The GL Rendering Context.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);                       // Show The Window
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);                      // Slightly Higher Priority
    SetFocus(hWnd);                             // Sets Keyboard Focus To The Window
    ReSizeGLScene(width, height);                       // Set Up Our Perspective GL Screen

    if (!InitGL())                              // Initialize Our Newly Created GL Window
    {
        KillGLWindow();                         // Reset The Display
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Initialization Failed.", (LPCWSTR)"ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return FALSE;                           // Return FALSE
    }

    return TRUE;                                // Success
}


// this function is used to draw objects in the scene.
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();                           // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);            // Move into space 6 units and -1.5 to the left
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                      // Begin drawing triagle
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Left
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Right
    glEnd();                            // Finished Drawing The Triangle
    glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);                   // Move Right 3 Units
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                      // Draw A Quad
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top Left
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top Right
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Right
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Left
    glEnd();                            // Done Drawing The Quad
    return TRUE;                                // Everything Went OK
}

// this function resizes and reinitializes the property of the opengl window when window is resized.
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height){
    if (height == 0){              // prevent a divide by zero
        height = 1;                // Making height equal one
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Resize the current viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);     // select the projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                // reset the projection matrix

    // Calculate theaspect ratio of the window
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);       // select the model view matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                 // reset the modelview matrix
}
// this function is called before closing the application to properly close the window.
GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid)
{
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0); // If so Switch back to the Desktop.
        ShowCursor(TRUE); // Show the mouse pointer.
    }
    if (hRC)
    {
        if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Release of DC and RC Failed", (LPCWSTR)"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        if (!wglDeleteContext(hRC))   // Are we able to delete the rendering context?
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Release of Rendering Context Failed", (LPCWSTR)"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        hRC = NULL; // set rendering context to null.
    }

    if (hDC && !ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC))                    // Are We Able To Release The DC
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Release Device Context Failed.", (LPCWSTR)"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hDC = NULL;                           // Set DC To NULL
    }

    if (hWnd && !DestroyWindow(hWnd))                   // Are We Able To Destroy The Window?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Could Not Release hWnd.", (LPCWSTR)"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hWnd = NULL;                          // Set hWnd To NULL
    }

    if (!UnregisterClass((LPCWSTR)"OpenGL", hInstance))               // Are We Able To Unregister Class
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Could Not Unregister Class.", (LPCWSTR)"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hInstance = NULL;                         // Set hInstance To NULL
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND    hWnd,                   // Handle For This Window
    UINT    uMsg,                   // Message For This Window
    WPARAM  wParam,                 // Additional Message Information
    LPARAM  lParam)                 // Additional Message Information
{
    switch (uMsg)                               // Check For Windows Messages
    {
    case WM_ACTIVATE:                       // Watch For Window Activate Message
    {
        if (!HIWORD(wParam))                    // Check Minimization State
        {
            active = TRUE;                    // Program Is Active
        }
        else
        {
            active = FALSE;                   // Program Is No Longer Active
        }

        return 0;                       // Return To The Message Loop
    }
    case WM_SYSCOMMAND:                     // Intercept System Commands
    {
        switch (wParam)                     // Check System Calls
        {
        case SC_SCREENSAVE:             // Screensaver Trying To Start?
        case SC_MONITORPOWER:               // Monitor Trying To Enter Powersave?
            return 0;                   // Prevent From Happening
        }
        break;                          // Exit
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:                          // Did We Receive A Close Message?
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);                 // Send A Quit Message
        return 0;                       // Jump Back
    }
    case WM_KEYDOWN:                        // Is A Key Being Held Down?
    {
        keys[wParam] = TRUE;                    // If So, Mark It As TRUE
        return 0;                       // Jump Back
    }
    case WM_KEYUP:                          // Has A Key Been Released?
    {
        keys[wParam] = FALSE;                   // If So, Mark It As FALSE
        return 0;                       // Jump Back
    }
    case WM_SIZE:                           // Resize The OpenGL Window
    {
        ReSizeGLScene(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));       // LoWord=Width, HiWord=Height
        return 0;                       // Jump Back
    }
    }
    // Pass All Unhandled Messages To DefWindowProc
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're most likely running into is, that the Windows APIs you use expect *wide character* strings, but the string literals you have in your source code are standard (narrow) characters. So for every 2 consecutive characters in your strings, Windows interprets it as a single wide character; which will very likely end up in some asian script if every two bytes of a wchar are nonzero.

Solution: Use the `_TEXT(…)` macro to surround your string literals, turning them into wide character strings.